# How to submit a correctly formatted DATE or TIME input value into a MSSQL datetime column?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, date, datetime

**QUESTION**

How to submit a correctly formatted **DATE** or **TIME** input value into a MSSQL **datetime** column?

**ASPX**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="Server" Type="date"/>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTime" runat="Server" Type="time"/>
```

**VB.NET**

```
Dim Date As Date = CType(Item.FindControl("txtDate"), TextBox).Text
Dim Time As Date = CType(Item.FindControl("txtTime"), TextBox).Text
```

**SUBMITTED VALUES**

```
13/2/2014
12:00
```

---

**NOTES**

I am very familiar with retriving a datetime field from sql and outputting just the time or date part.

I would normally set txtDate and txtTime as a string but would like to know other ways to populate a sql datetime field when only the DATE or TIME is submitted. (Either in aspx, vb.net or mssql).

In my example when a date is submitted the time portion is not relevant and when a time is submitted the date portion is not relevant however the complete string will need submitting to sql to fill the datetime field correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server has defaults for `DATE` and `TIME` when you insert into a `DATETIME` column

```
DECLARE @DateTimeTest TABLE (
    EnteredDate DATETIME
    )
DECLARE @DateOnly DATE = '12/1/2012'
DECLARE @TimeOnly TIME = '12:00PM'

SELECT * FROM @DateTimeTest

INSERT INTO @DateTimeTest
VALUES (@DateOnly)

INSERT INTO @DateTimeTest
VALUES (@TimeOnly)

SELECT * FROM @DateTimeTest
```

This returns

[image]

If you want to set your own defaults, just append whichever is missing before inserting into the table.

Comment: This is great a new to me. I will give it a try thanks. Do you recommend that the fields are submitted as strings from the input?

Comment: You get the same result since going from `VARCHAR` to `DATE`, `TIME`, and `DATETIME` are all [implicit conversions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

Comment: Beware of date format. `yyyy-mm-dd` and/or `hh:mi:ss.nnn` is what you should be aiming for. 5/6/2014 is ambiguous and the result depends on various settings... is it May or June? ;)

Comment: @gvee Passing in yyyy-mm-dd and/or hh:mi:ss.nnn is the same since those conform to the ISO format but you do raise a good point about the mm/dd vs dd/mm.  I would defer to the application programmer to make sure they give the user a prompt on what format they should be entering or use a calendar control to remove ambiguity.

Comment: @TTeeple Never trust your users `;)` equally, never trust your applications/servers/environment settings, so you should always make the values given to the computer are unambiguous. Aim for ISO format in all your code.